# OPEN XML and Powertools

Tags: openxml

I am merging a couple word documents together and the very last one is static content and I need to add a date to the end of the document but the powertool WmlDocument object doesn't seem to work to add text.  How can I add text?

```
List <Source> sources = new List<Source>();
sources.Add(new Source(report, false));
sources.Add(new Source(sig, false));
WmlDocument doc = DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources);
doc.MainDocumentPart.Add() // nothing here works.
doc.MainDocumentPart.Add(new Text("stuff"));  // not working
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document  -- NULL
doc.SaveAs("blah.docx") //creates doc.
```

I don't want to save the file to disk then open it up.

Answer (score 0):

I opened it up using WordprocessingDocument and edited it through that object model.